# badly performing query when IS NOT NULL used in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, null

I have a query that returns results in under a second (115 rows) if I use `IS NULL` in the `WHERE` clause, but when I change it to `IS NOT NULL`
its taking 1 minute 16 seconds (129 rows). The column I'm testing for `NULL` is indexed, I just cant figure out why the 2 WHERE clauses should differ so greatly, can anyone see where I'm going wrong here ?

I'm using SQL Server 2012

```
SELECT position.counterparty,
       position.positiontype,
       contract.contract,
       Trade.cstcontractstart AS ContractStartDate,
       Trade.cstcontractend AS ContractEndDate,
       Trade.trade AS TradeID,
       Trade.tradedate AS TradeDate,
       powerquantity.begtime AS StartDateTime,
       powerquantity.endtime AS EndDateTime,
       CASE
            WHEN CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS int) <= 31 THEN 'M'
            WHEN CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS int) > 31
             AND CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS int) <= 93 THEN 'Q'
            WHEN CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS int) > 93
             AND CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS int) <= 183 THEN 'S'
            ELSE 'M'
       END AS BlockDescription,
       CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS int) AS Days,
       CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0 AS HoursInPeriod,
       dbo.WorkingDays(powerquantity.begtime, powerquantity.endtime) AS WorkingDays,
       dbo.WorkingDays(powerquantity.begtime, powerquantity.endtime) * 24 AS WorkingHours,
       SUM(CASE WHEN LEFT(powerquantity.tsperiod, 2) = 'WD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS WD_EFA_Periods,
       SUM(CASE WHEN LEFT(powerquantity.tsperiod, 2) = 'WE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS WE_EFA_Periods,
       CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0 - (dbo.WorkingDays(powerquantity.begtime, powerquantity.endtime) * 24) AS WeekendHours,
       CASE
            WHEN fee.feemode = 'FIXED' THEN CASE
                                                 WHEN position.unit = 'MW' THEN CASE DATEPART(HOUR, powerquantity.begtime)
                                                                                     WHEN 0 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he1) * fee.pricediff
                                                                                     WHEN 1 THEN CASE DATEPART(MONTH, powerquantity.begtime)
                                                                                                      WHEN 10 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he25) * fee.pricediff
                                                                                                      ELSE (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he2) * fee.pricediff
                                                                                                 END
                                                                                     WHEN 2 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he3) * fee.pricediff
                                                                                     WHEN 3 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he4) * fee.pricediff
                                                                                     WHEN 4 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he5) * fee.pricediff
                                                                                     WHEN 5 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he6) * fee.pricediff
                                                                                     WHEN 6 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he7) * fee.pricediff
                                                                                     WHEN 7 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he8) * fee.pricediff
                                                                                     WHEN 8 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he9) * fee.pricediff
                                                                                     WHEN 9 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he10) * fee.pricediff
                                                                                     WHEN 10 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he11) * fee.pricediff
                                                                                     WHEN 11 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he12) * fee.pricediff
                                                                                     WHEN 12 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he13) * fee.pricediff
                                                                                     WHEN 13 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he14) * fee.pricediff
                                                                                     WHEN 14 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he15) * fee.pricediff
                                                                                     WHEN 15 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he16) * fee.pricediff
                                                                                     WHEN 16 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he17) * fee.pricediff
                                                                                     WHEN 17 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he18) * fee.pricediff
                                                                                     WHEN 18 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he19) * fee.pricediff
                                                                                     WHEN 19 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he20) * fee.pricediff
                                                                                     WHEN 20 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he21) * fee.pricediff
                                                                                     WHEN 21 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he22) * fee.pricediff
                                                                                     WHEN 22 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he23) * fee.pricediff
                                                                                     WHEN 23 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he24) * fee.pricediff
                                                                                END
                                                 ELSE CASE DATEPART(HOUR, powerquantity.begtime)
                                                           WHEN 0 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he1) * fee.pricediff
                                                           WHEN 1 THEN CASE DATEPART(MONTH, powerquantity.begtime)
                                                                            WHEN 10 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he25) * fee.pricediff
                                                                            ELSE MAX(powerquantity.he2) * fee.pricediff
                                                                       END
                                                           WHEN 2 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he3) * fee.pricediff
                                                           WHEN 3 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he4) * fee.pricediff
                                                           WHEN 4 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he5) * fee.pricediff
                                                           WHEN 5 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he6) * fee.pricediff
                                                           WHEN 6 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he7) * fee.pricediff
                                                           WHEN 7 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he8) * fee.pricediff
                                                           WHEN 8 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he9) * fee.pricediff
                                                           WHEN 9 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he10) * fee.pricediff
                                                           WHEN 10 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he11) * fee.pricediff
                                                           WHEN 11 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he12) * fee.pricediff
                                                           WHEN 12 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he13) * fee.pricediff
                                                           WHEN 13 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he14) * fee.pricediff
                                                           WHEN 14 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he15) * fee.pricediff
                                                           WHEN 15 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he16) * fee.pricediff
                                                           WHEN 16 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he17) * fee.pricediff
                                                           WHEN 17 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he18) * fee.pricediff
                                                           WHEN 18 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he19) * fee.pricediff
                                                           WHEN 19 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he20) * fee.pricediff
                                                           WHEN 20 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he21) * fee.pricediff
                                                           WHEN 21 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he22) * fee.pricediff
                                                           WHEN 22 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he23) * fee.pricediff
                                                           WHEN 23 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he24) * fee.pricediff
                                                      END
                                            END
            ELSE CASE
                      WHEN position.unit = 'MW' THEN CASE DATEPART(HOUR, powerquantity.begtime)
                                                          WHEN 0 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he1) * fee.priceindex
                                                          WHEN 1 THEN CASE DATEPART(MONTH, powerquantity.begtime)
                                                                           WHEN 10 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he25) * fee.priceindex
                                                                           ELSE (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he2) * fee.priceindex
                                                                      END
                                                          WHEN 2 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he3) * fee.priceindex
                                                          WHEN 3 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he4) * fee.priceindex
                                                          WHEN 4 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he5) * fee.priceindex
                                                          WHEN 5 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he6) * fee.priceindex
                                                          WHEN 6 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he7) * fee.priceindex
                                                          WHEN 7 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he8) * fee.priceindex
                                                          WHEN 8 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he9) * fee.priceindex
                                                          WHEN 9 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he10) * fee.priceindex
                                                          WHEN 10 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he11) * fee.priceindex
                                                          WHEN 11 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he12) * fee.priceindex
                                                          WHEN 12 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he13) * fee.priceindex
                                                          WHEN 13 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he14) * fee.priceindex
                                                          WHEN 14 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he15) * fee.priceindex
                                                          WHEN 15 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he16) * fee.priceindex
                                                          WHEN 16 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he17) * fee.priceindex
                                                          WHEN 17 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he18) * fee.priceindex
                                                          WHEN 18 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he19) * fee.priceindex
                                                          WHEN 19 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he20) * fee.priceindex
                                                          WHEN 20 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he21) * fee.priceindex
                                                          WHEN 21 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he22) * fee.priceindex
                                                          WHEN 22 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he23) * fee.priceindex
                                                          WHEN 23 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he24) * fee.priceindex
                                                     END
                      ELSE CASE DATEPART(HOUR, powerquantity.begtime)
                                WHEN 0 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he1) * fee.priceindex
                                WHEN 1 THEN CASE DATEPART(MONTH, powerquantity.begtime)
                                                 WHEN 10 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he25) * fee.priceindex
                                                 ELSE MAX(powerquantity.he2) * fee.priceindex
                                            END
                                WHEN 2 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he3) * fee.priceindex
                                WHEN 3 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he4) * fee.priceindex
                                WHEN 4 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he5) * fee.priceindex
                                WHEN 5 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he6) * fee.priceindex
                                WHEN 6 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he7) * fee.priceindex
                                WHEN 7 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he8) * fee.priceindex
                                WHEN 8 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he9) * fee.priceindex
                                WHEN 9 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he10) * fee.priceindex
                                WHEN 10 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he11) * fee.priceindex
                                WHEN 11 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he12) * fee.priceindex
                                WHEN 12 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he13) * fee.priceindex
                                WHEN 13 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he14) * fee.priceindex
                                WHEN 14 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he15) * fee.priceindex
                                WHEN 15 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he16) * fee.priceindex
                                WHEN 16 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he17) * fee.priceindex
                                WHEN 17 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he18) * fee.priceindex
                                WHEN 18 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he19) * fee.priceindex
                                WHEN 19 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he20) * fee.priceindex
                                WHEN 20 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he21) * fee.priceindex
                                WHEN 21 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he22) * fee.priceindex
                                WHEN 22 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he23) * fee.priceindex
                                WHEN 23 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he24) * fee.priceindex
                           END
                 END
       END AS BlockCostGBP,
       CASE DATEPART(HOUR, powerquantity.begtime)
            WHEN 0 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he1)
            WHEN 1 THEN CASE DATEPART(MONTH, powerquantity.begtime)
                             WHEN 10 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he25)
                             ELSE MAX(powerquantity.he2)
                        END
            WHEN 2 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he3)
            WHEN 3 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he4)
            WHEN 4 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he5)
            WHEN 5 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he6)
            WHEN 6 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he7)
            WHEN 7 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he8)
            WHEN 8 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he9)
            WHEN 9 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he10)
            WHEN 10 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he11)
            WHEN 11 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he12)
            WHEN 12 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he13)
            WHEN 13 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he14)
            WHEN 14 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he15)
            WHEN 15 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he16)
            WHEN 16 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he17)
            WHEN 17 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he18)
            WHEN 18 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he19)
            WHEN 19 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he20)
            WHEN 20 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he21)
            WHEN 21 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he22)
            WHEN 22 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he23)
            WHEN 23 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he24)
       END AS Volume,
       CASE
            WHEN position.unit = 'MW' THEN CASE DATEPART(HOUR, powerquantity.begtime)
                                                WHEN 0 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he1)
                                                WHEN 1 THEN CASE DATEPART(MONTH, powerquantity.begtime)
                                                                 WHEN 10 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he25)
                                                                 ELSE (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he2)
                                                            END
                                                WHEN 2 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he3)
                                                WHEN 3 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he4)
                                                WHEN 4 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he5)
                                                WHEN 5 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he6)
                                                WHEN 6 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he7)
                                                WHEN 7 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he8)
                                                WHEN 8 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he9)
                                                WHEN 9 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he10)
                                                WHEN 10 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he11)
                                                WHEN 11 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he12)
                                                WHEN 12 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he13)
                                                WHEN 13 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he14)
                                                WHEN 14 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he15)
                                                WHEN 15 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he16)
                                                WHEN 16 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he17)
                                                WHEN 17 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he18)
                                                WHEN 18 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he19)
                                                WHEN 19 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he20)
                                                WHEN 20 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he21)
                                                WHEN 21 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he22)
                                                WHEN 22 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he23)
                                                WHEN 23 THEN (CAST((powerquantity.endtime - powerquantity.begtime) AS float) * 24.0) * MAX(powerquantity.he24)
                                           END
            ELSE CASE DATEPART(HOUR, powerquantity.begtime)
                      WHEN 0 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he1)
                      WHEN 1 THEN CASE DATEPART(MONTH, powerquantity.begtime)
                                       WHEN 10 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he25)
                                       ELSE MAX(powerquantity.he2)
                                  END
                      WHEN 2 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he3)
                      WHEN 3 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he4)
                      WHEN 4 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he5)
                      WHEN 5 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he6)
                      WHEN 6 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he7)
                      WHEN 7 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he8)
                      WHEN 8 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he9)
                      WHEN 9 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he10)
                      WHEN 10 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he11)
                      WHEN 11 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he12)
                      WHEN 12 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he13)
                      WHEN 13 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he14)
                      WHEN 14 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he15)
                      WHEN 15 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he16)
                      WHEN 16 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he17)
                      WHEN 17 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he18)
                      WHEN 18 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he19)
                      WHEN 19 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he20)
                      WHEN 20 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he21)
                      WHEN 21 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he22) * fee.pricediff
                      WHEN 22 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he23) * fee.pricediff
                      WHEN 23 THEN MAX(powerquantity.he24) * fee.pricediff
                 END
       END AS MWh,
       position.unit,
       powerquantity.timeunit,
       CASE WHEN fee.feemode = 'FIXED' THEN fee.pricediff ELSE fee.priceindex END AS GBPMWh,
       fee.feemode
FROM Trade
     INNER JOIN position ON Trade.trade = position.trade
     INNER JOIN powerposition ON position.position = powerposition.position
     INNER JOIN powerquantity ON powerposition.position = powerquantity.position
                             AND powerposition.posdetail = powerquantity.posdetail
     INNER JOIN contract ON position.contract = contract.contract
                        AND contract.contracttype IN ('ETSA', 'SETSA')
     INNER JOIN fee ON position.position = fee.dbvalue
                   AND fee.dbcolumn = 'POSITION'
                   AND fee.feemethod = 'COMMODITY PRICE'
WHERE contract.contract = '110156'
  AND powerquantity.posstatus = 1
  AND position.loadshape IS NULL
GROUP BY powerquantity.begtime,
         powerquantity.endtime,
         Trade.trade,
         Trade.tradedate,
         fee.pricediff,
         fee.priceindex,
         position.unit,
         contract.contract,
         fee.feemode,
         powerquantity.timeunit,
         position.counterparty,
         position.positiontype,
         Trade.cstcontractstart,
         Trade.cstcontractend
ORDER BY powerquantity.begtime,
         powerquantity.endtime;
```

Comment: `IS NULL` tests for one specific value -- that is, `NULL`. `IS NOT NULL` tests for everything else. This is a radical difference; usually the one between an index seek and and index scan, aside from the difference in estimated number of rows (which influences the rest of the query). This is the generic answer without looking at your query's execution plan, which you should do if you want to get into the details.

Comment: _can anyone see where I'm going wrong here_ - really? ;)

Comment: Check the actual execution plans. Most likely, many more rows qualify for the `IS NOT NULL` vs `IS NULL`.

Comment: The wild indentation makes it almost impossible to read the SQL. For maintainability and readability I'd probably break it down into smaller queries if possible, inserting the results into indexed # tables along the way, before bringing the results together at the end...

Comment: ok guys, thanks for the advice, Ill look into optimising the query, hopefully I can gain some performance improvements somewhere.  On a side note I really cant see why rather than be constructive and help someone Fabio would rather inject an element of sarcasm into their response instead of actually offering assistance, why bother ?